# C# Serialization error

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I'm trying to store  object of Employee in Session (DB Based), When i do this I'm getting serialization error "Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer'"

```
[Serializable]
public class Employee
{
    ... 
public List<System.ComponenetModel.DataAnnotation.ValidationResult> MyValidationResult
  { get; set; }
}
```

I figured out it is happening when it tries to  serialize MyValidationResult it is happening, Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you check if `ValidationResult` is Serializable ?

Comment: It is not marked as serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`NonSerializedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx). Add a backing field and don't use an auto-implemented property and add the NonSerializedAttribute to the field and you should be good to go.

Comment: well, that attribute tells the serializer not to attempt to serialize that field, which means that ValidationResult or one of it's members probably isn't marked as serializable.

Answer (score 1):

ValidationResult cannot be serialized because it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. If you need to save the validations in session state, you'll have to come up with another class to do so. If you don't need it, then apply the NonSerialized attribute to the property.